# http post method in angular throws argument not provided

Tags: angular, spring-boot, api, http, post

On the backend I have the POST method which works fine through postman using this url:

```
http://localhost:8087/termine/updateProduct/1
```

However in angular it throws error (on IDE - visual studio code) **An argument for 'product' was not provided** for my updateProduct method:

```
updateProduct(id: number, product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.post<Product>(`${this.baseUrl}/updateProduct/${id}`, product);
  }
```

Here is the code in backend/API:

```
    @PostMapping("updateProduct/{productId}")
    public boolean updateProduct(@RequestBody Product productDetails,@PathVariable("productId") String productId) throws JsonProcessingException, ProductExistsException{
        boolean result= productService.updateProduct(productDetails, productId);
        return result;
    }
```

All the rest of these methods work fine:

```
  getAllProducts(){
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.baseUrl + "/getAllProducts");
  }

  addProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product>{
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.baseUrl + "/addProduct", product);
  }

  deleteProduct(id: number):Observable<{}>{
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/deleteProduct/${id}`);
  }

  getProductById(id: number){
    return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.baseUrl}/getProductById/${id}`);
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it response from backend? Can you see your request being executed in `DevTools -> Network` ?

Comment: @KamilChlebek I m getting this error on my ide - visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

You check API: updateProduct (method: Put or post)
if method = Put

```
updateProduct(id: number, product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/updateProduct/${id}`, product);
  }
```

Comment: The method is post and it works fine on backend / postman

Comment: Can i add Linkedin? we can talk about this issue. https://www.linkedin.com/in/linh-nguyen-96919a143/

Comment: You should debugger on function UpdateProduct

Comment: This is not even hitting the function yet. The error is showing on my ide - visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

I was missing Product after http.post

```
updateProduct(id: number, product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.post<Product>(`${this.baseUrl}/updateProduct/${id}`, product);
  }
```